# How to get checkboxes verticaly aligned with other input fields

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net MVC 5, I'm trying to get the three checkboxes aligned with the other fields as shown below (red line indicates where I want them)

[image]

The code for the Diocese and Acknowledgement - the rest are much the same but for different fields - is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Diocese, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Diocese, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-width-xlarge" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Diocese, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Acknowledgement, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
    <div class="col-md-10 checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Acknowledgement)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Acknowledgement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought the md-x classes would have aligned them, but I'm obviously wrong there :)

Comment: can you post all the relevant code / a demo?

Comment: Please post rendered html instead of razor code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Changed EditorFor to CheckBoxFor, put a label around it, set padding-left to 15.